# htaccess rewriterule check if variable exist and replace

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, preg-replace, preg-match

I try to get working my htaccess.

This is my link:

```
https://www.link.net/1N02?var1=100
```

But I need a working rule to get

```
https://www.link.net/link.php?id=1N02&var1=100
```

I tried this

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$          link.php?id=$1 [L]
```

But this give me only this back

```
link.net/link.php?id=1N02hV?var1=100
```

So I need your help. I must check if a "var" variable exist and then replace it with a rule. As info... var1 is only an example it can also be var2, var3, var4... but allways starts with var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^var [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /link.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi, but then I will get back https://www.link.net/link.php?id=1N02?var1=100 and not https://www.link.net/link.php?id=1N02&var1=100

Comment: The rule I gave you rewrites to `/link.php?id=xxx&varN=yyy`. You must have something else that messes things up